# current flow tangent to the wire

Tags: electromagnetism, electricity

In a thread flowing a current. How is it possible that the current is always tangent to the wire, regardless how the driver is "bent"?

Comment: Not clear what you are asking. Please add more detail about the context of your question.

Answer (score 0):

Electrons transported by electric fields in metal wires have typical energies close to the Fermi level of the metal. The Fermi level is usually a couple of $eV$ below the surface energy barrier called work function which has to be overcome to leave the metal. Thus the metal conduction electrons hitting the surface barrier are simply reflected and continue their drift motion along the path of the wire.